# Extracting Resolved Comment Status from Microsoft Word Document

Tags: xml, ms-word, comments, python-docx

I am trying to find a way to extract resolved comment status from a word document. Here is the current way I am extracting start, end, authors, and date from within comments. Is there a way to grab if a comment was resolved? I have played around and tried looking up the xml of the comments but my code isn't grabbing anything when debugging.

#extracting start, end, authors, and dates of comments within document

```
start_com = {x.group(1): x.start() for x in re.finditer(r'<w:commentRangeStart.*?w:id="(.*?)"', doc)}

end_com = {x.group(1): x.end() for x in re.finditer(r'<w:commentRangeEnd.*?w:id="(.*?)".*?>', doc)}

 authors = {x.get('w:id'): x.get('w:author') for x in comments.find_all('w:comment')}

dates= {x.get('w:id'): x.get('w:date') for x in comments.find_all('w:comment')}
```

#this is what I have tried for resolved tag to see if grabbing the revision history would work.

```
 resolved_tags = {x.group(1): x for x in re.finditer(r'<w:rsidR>.*?w:id="(,*?)"', doc)}
```